# google app script create a chart based on an array of objects

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts

I tried to create a scatter chart in google sheet app script. The values should be retrieved from an array of objects

`var Data = [{ID:1, X:2, Y:2},{ID:2, X:3, Y:3},{ID:3, X:4, Y:4}];`

the function to build a scatter chart is:

```
`var Spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadSheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var Range = Data;
var chart = sheet.newChart().setChartType(Charts.ChartType.Scatter).addRange(Range).build()
}`
```

I think there is an issue with retrieving the data from the object.

best regards.

find a solution to retrieve the data from the object. The x any y coordinates are needed to build the scatter chart

Comment: Your `Range` is the array of objects, not a [Range object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) from the spreadsheet.  You would have to write your data object to a sheet first and then reference the range that values reside in.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of creating a scatter plot.
[image]

**Code.gs**

```
function test() {
  try {
    var Data = [{ID:1, X:2, Y:2},{ID:2, X:3, Y:3},{ID:3, X:4, Y:4}];
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let values = [["ID","X","Y"]];
    Data.forEach( object => {
        values.push([object.ID,object.X,object.Y]);
      }
    );
    console.log(values);
    sheet.getRange(1,1,values.length,3).setValues(values);
    let range = sheet.getRange(1,2,values.length,2)
    let chart = sheet.newChart()
                  .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.SCATTER)
                  .addRange(range)
                  .setNumHeaders(1)
                  .setPosition(5,5,0,0)
                  .setOption("hAxis",{title:"X"})
                  .setOption("vAxis",{title:"Y"})
                  .build();

    sheet.insertChart(chart);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**References**

- [Sheet.getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [Sheet.newChart()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#newChart())

Comment: In this case we are puting the X and Y values in the cell to build a chart. I would like to use the object array in the script only. Without putting the values in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks to TheEizEd for providing the solution.

Comment: I don't know of any way to simply use data to construct a chart.  I believe charts are always linked to a range in a spreadsheet.

Comment: charts seem to always be linked to a range, unfortunately