# draw scatter plot in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, scatter-plot

i am looking for a solution to draw a scatter plot based on an array of objects in java respectively with a google apps script.

i know how to preceed in python.

```
# Program to draw scatter plot using Dataframe.plot
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
  
# Prepare data
data={'Name':['Dhanashri', 'Smita', 'Rutuja',
              'Sunita', 'Poonam', 'Srushti'],
      'Age':[20, 18, 27, 50, 12, 15]}
  
# Load data into DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data);
  
# Draw a scatter plot
df.plot.scatter(x = 'Name', y = 'Age', s = 100);
```

how can i do draw a scatter in google apps?
Thats the array of objects in google scripting

```
var Data = [{ID:1, X:2, Y:2},{ID:2, X:3, Y:3},{ID:3, X:4, Y:4}];
```

Comment: What do you want to plot to, Google Spreadsheet, browser?

Comment: i prefer to plot in the spreadsheet. a brower based plot is also sufficient...

Comment: i can write the values in the spreadsheet first. Based on this i can create a scatter plot. But this is not the aspired goal...

Comment: The SpreadsheetApp chart builders all require data come from a range in the spreadsheet so if you don't want to create a sheet and convert your objects to values you can't do it.  If you want to create the plot outside of the spreadsheet and then copy it in i would suggest you look at [d3](https://d3js.org/) first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [google app script create a chart based on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76634956/google-app-script-create-a-chart-based-on-an-array-of-objects)